# Saving edited data via formsets

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to edit multiple rows of data in a model via formsets. In my rendered form, I use javascript to delete (hide and assign DELETE) rows, and then save changes with post.

My view:

```
def procedure_template_modification_alt(request, cliniclabel, template_id):
    msg = ''
    clinicobj = Clinic.objects.get(label=cliniclabel)
    template_id = int(template_id)
    template= ProcedureTemplate.objects.get(templid = template_id)       
    formset = ProcedureModificationFormset(queryset=SectionHeading.objects.filter(template = template))   

    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.POST.get)
        # Create a formset instance with POST data.
        formset = ProcedureModificationFormset(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            print("Form is valid")
            instances = formset.save(commit=False)
            print(f'instances:{instances}')
            for instance in instances:
                print(f'Instance: {instance}')
                instance.template = template
                instance.save()
            msg = "Changes saved successfully."
            print("Deleted forms:")
            for form in formset.deleted_forms:
                print(form.cleaned_data)
        else:
            print("Form is invalid")
            print(formset.errors)
            msg = "Your changes could not be saved as the data you entered is invalid!"

    template= ProcedureTemplate.objects.get(templid = template_id)
    headings = SectionHeading.objects.filter(template = template)

    return render(request, 'procedures/create_procedure_formset_alt.html',
    {
        'template': template,
        'formset': formset,
        'headings': headings,
        'msg': msg,
        'rnd_num': randomnumber(),
    })
```

My models:

```
class ProcedureTemplate(models.Model):
    templid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=5000, default='', blank=True)
    clinic = models.ForeignKey(Clinic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.description}'        

class SectionHeading(models.Model):
    procid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    default = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    sortorder = models.IntegerField(default=1000)

    fieldtype_choice = (
        ('heading1', 'Heading1'),
        ('heading2', 'Heading2'),
        )
    fieldtype = models.CharField(
        choices=fieldtype_choice, max_length=100, default='heading1')

    template = models.ForeignKey(ProcedureTemplate, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} [{self.procid}]'
```

My forms:

```
class ProcedureCrMetaForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SectionHeading
        fields = [
            'name',
            'default',
            'sortorder',
            'fieldtype',
            'procid'
        ]
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['name'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
        self.fields['default'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
        self.fields['sortorder'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
        self.fields['fieldtype'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})

ProcedureCreationFormset = formset_factory(ProcedureCrMetaForm, extra=3)
ProcedureModificationFormset = modelformset_factory(SectionHeading, ProcedureCrMetaForm, 
    fields=('name', 'default', 'sortorder','fieldtype', 'procid'),
    can_delete=True,
    extra=0
    # widgets={"name": Textarea()}
    )
```

The template:

```
{% block content %} {% load widget_tweaks %}
<div class="container">
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <div class="row my-1">
        <div class="col-sm-2">Name</div>
        <div class="col-sm-22">
            <input type="text" name="procedurename" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter name of procedure (E.g. DNE)"
                value="{{ template.title }}" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row my-1">
        <div class="col-sm-2">Description</div>
        <div class="col-sm-22">
            <input type="text" name="proceduredesc" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter description of procedure (E.g. Diagnostic Nasal Endoscopy)"
                value="{{ template.description }}" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %} {{ formset.management_form }}
        <div class="row mt-3">
            <div class="col-sm-1">Select</div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">Heading</div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">Default (Normal description)</div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">Sort Order</div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">Type</div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">Action</div>
        </div>
        {% for form in formset %}
        <div class="row procrow" id="row{{ forloop.counter0 }}">
            <div class="" style="display: none;">{{ form.procid }}</div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                {{ form.name }}

            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <div class="input-group">
                    {{ form.default }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div class="input-group">
                    {{ form.sortorder }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="input-group">
                    {{ form.fieldtype }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button id="add{{ forloop.counter0 }}" class="btn btn-success add-row">+</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button id="del{{ forloop.counter0 }}" class="btn btn-danger del-row">-</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %} {% endif %}
        <div class="row my-3">
            <div class="col-sm-8"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-append mx-1">
                        <button id="save_report" type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fal fa-shield-check"></i>
                            Save Report Format</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group-append mx-1">
                        <button id="save_report" type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fal fa-times-hexagon"></i>
                            Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8"></div>
        </div>

        <div>
            {% for dict in formset.errors %} {% for error in dict.values %} {{ error }} {% endfor %} {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </form>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

My data is displayed as below (Screenshot). I make changes with javascript when the delete button is pressed, so that the html becomes like this:

```
<div class="row procrow" id="row2" style="display: none;">
    <div class="" style="display: none;"><input type="hidden" name="form-2-procid" value="25" id="id_form-2-procid"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" name="form-2-name" value="a" maxlength="200" class="form-control" id="id_form-2-name">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" name="form-2-default" value="v" maxlength="1000" class="form-control" id="id_form-2-default">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="number" name="form-2-sortorder" value="1000" class="form-control" id="id_form-2-sortorder">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="input-group">
            <select name="form-2-fieldtype" class="form-control" id="id_form-2-fieldtype">
<option value="heading1" selected="">Heading1</option>

<option value="heading2">Heading2</option>
</select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <button id="add2" class="btn btn-success add-row">+</button>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <button id="del2" class="btn btn-danger del-row">-</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="checkbox" name="form-2-DELETE" id="id_form-2-DELETE" checked=""></div>
```

On submitting the data, I get the following output, and data does not reflect the deletion I did. It displays the same thing again. There are no errors. But my edited data is not being saved.

Output:

```
<bound method MultiValueDict.get of <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['ka3avICLigV6TaMBK5a8zeVJlizhtsKW5OTDBLlYorKd7Iji9zRxCX2vvjBv6xKu'], 'form-TOTAL_FORMS': ['3'], 'form-INITIAL_FORMS': ['3'], 'form-MIN_NUM_FORMS': ['0'], 'form-MAX_NUM_FORMS': ['1000'], 'form-0-procid': ['23'], 'form-0-name': ['External ear canal'], 'form-0-default': ['Bilateral external ear canals appear normal. No discharge.'], 'form-0-sortorder': ['100'], 'form-0-fieldtype': ['heading1'], 'form-1-procid': ['24'], 'form-1-name': ['Tympanic membrane'], 'form-1-default': ['Tympanic membrane appears normal. Mobility not assessed.'], 'form-1-sortorder': ['500'], 'form-1-fieldtype': ['heading1'], 'form-2-procid': ['25'], 'form-2-name': ['a'], 'form-2-default': ['v'], 'form-2-sortorder': ['1000'], 'form-2-fieldtype': ['heading1'], 'form-2-DELETE': ['on']}>>
Form is valid
instances:[]
Deleted forms:
{'name': 'a', 'default': 'v', 'sortorder': 1000, 'fieldtype': 'heading1', 'procid': <SectionHeading: a [25]>, 'DELETE': True}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You're not saving the formset (`commit=False` and you loop through each instance and save it) and you're not deleting any of the instances that are marked for deletion. How do you expect instances to get deleted?

Answer (score 2):

You actually need to delete the instances: Loop through the formsets' `deleted_objects` property after you called `saved(commit=False)` and delete them.